# How to get node ids from within Javascript using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

You can use the Puppeteer devtools protocol to query nodes. For example:

```
    const doc = await page._client.send('DOM.getDocument');
    const nodes = await page._client.send('DOM.querySelectorAll', {
        nodeId: doc.root.nodeId,
        selector: '*'
    });
```

Is there a way to get these node ids from within Javascript that is executing in the browser context?

Then, I can run some complex Javascript code inside the browser and return the node ids to puppeteer.